# Laravel - get size from uploaded file

Tags: laravel

I have saved a file with this command

```
$newFile = [
            'event_id' => $event->id,
            'path' => $storePath
           ];

EventFile::create($newFile);
```

I can get the path to the file for a link like this:

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($file->path);
```

But there is no data about the file size. How can i get the file size in blade view???

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**Laravel 5^**

```
$request->file('file')->getSize(); // in bytes
```

**Laravel 4**

```
$request->file('file')->getClientSize(); // getClientSize() is deprecated in Laravel 5
```

Comment: in blade view there is no $request variable

Comment: Well, you need to call it in your controller and pass it to database or blade view...

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out. I have made a new table column for file size and when the file is created i save the file size also...so i can call $file->size

Comment: I would like to know the in which unit is represented the integer returned, I mean kb, mb, bits, bytes?

Comment: getClientSize() returns size of file in bytes

Comment: $request->file('file')->getSize(); <- not work, if uploading a file grather than 3mb, return false

Answer (score 11):

The more Simpler way is to use `Storage Facade` if you have already stored / uploaded file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function get_size($file_path)
{
    return Storage::size($file_path);
}
```

Or if you are using `S3` Bucket then you can modify the above function like  below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function get_size($file_path)
{
    return Storage::disk('s3')->size($file_path);
}
```

Check [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)

Comment: But you can't do that if the file is not uploaded yet and on the server... I was referring to a file in the actual request... that is going to be uploaded.

Answer (score 6):

```
getClientSize() is deprecated starting version 4.1. Use getSize() instead.
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.1/UPGRADE-4.1.md#httpfoundation

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Could you please follow the guidelines for posting [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Well, I believe since Laravel 5.7 you should use `getSize()` method instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Very simple(Proper Laravel Way):**

```
//add this at the top of your controller
use File;

// add this with in your function
$size = File::size($PATH_OF_FILE);
```

Comment: But you can't do that if the file is not uploaded yet and on the server... I was referring to a file in the actual request... that is going to be uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

laravel 8

```
  $imageSize = $request->file('file')->getSize();
$fil->size = number_format($imageSize / 1048576,2);
```

> $file->size My Table Change It With Your DB Table

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls) for version 8.0:

> When using the local driver, all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory.

So the **root** of your local storage here is the `public/` directory within `storage/app/`

You can Specify the method to get file size in your File Model like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class File extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'file_path'
    ];

    public function getFileSize() 
    {
        // Ensure $this->file_path begins with '/public/';
        return Storage::size($this->file_path);
    }
}
```

And use it like this within your blade file

```html
<div>{{ $file->getFileSize() }}</div>
```

If you use it this way, `$this->file_path` must have the format: `/public/optional_subdirectory/file_name`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need to get all the files from storage and calculate their sizes.

```
  public function backups()
    {
        $directory = "backup";
        
        $allFiles = Storage::allFiles($directory);
        $files =[];
        foreach($allFiles as $file){
            $size = Storage::size($file)/1024;
            array_push($files,['file'=>$file,'size'=>$size]);
        }
        return response()->json($files);
    }
```