# file type post return file size is zero in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

this is the scenario
I'm uploading 858 KB file
but in Controller it is 0kb 
and when I'm saving in storage_path()  it was empty

I'm saving the Image on /storage  and it was corrupted 
How can I fix this

```
   //this is the controller

   $input = $request->all();
   echo  $request->file('image_path')->getClientSize();
   dd($input);
```

> **this is the return of dd **
>           0

```
"image_path" => UploadedFile {#30 ▼-originalName: "Tulips.jpg"mimeType:"application/octet-stream"-size: 0-error: 6
```

//  this is the view  with blade form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'test2', 'files'=> true)) !!}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::text('title',Input::old('title'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'What is your title?']) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('image', 'Your Image') !!}
                                {!! Form::file('image_path') !!}
                                <p class="help-block">Hey! Please don't upload over 15MB images!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('caption', 'Don\'t miss to caption!') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('caption',Input::old('caption'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your caption']) !!}
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::submit('Post  now!',['class'=>'btn btn-info']) !!}
                            {!!Form::close() !!}
```

// I also try html form

```
<form id="pdf" action="{{ route('test2') }}" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image_path">
<span id="imgName">Choose a File</span>
<input type="text" name="_token" value=" 
    {{csrf_token()}}">
<input type="file" name="image_path" 
      id="path" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995731/laravel-get-size-from-uploaded-file

Answer (score 0):

`getClientSize()` is deprecated in Laravel. use `$request->file('image_path')->getSize()`;

As it mentioned in the Laravel Source.

```
 /**
     * Returns the file size.
     *
     * It is extracted from the request from which the file has been uploaded.
     * Then it should not be considered as a safe value.
     *
     * @deprecated since Symfony 4.1, use getSize() instead.
     *
     * @return int|null The file sizes
     */
    public function getClientSize()
    {
        @trigger_error(sprintf('The "%s()" method is deprecated since Symfony 4.1. Use getSize() instead.', __METHOD__), E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        return $this->getSize();
    }
```

Comment: the file size  is zero

Comment: but I'm uploading 858 KB file

Comment: @kenjilast make sure fileinfo extension is enabled

Comment: it   is   enabled  , I'm  working for solution for 3 days and  still can't fix this

Answer (score 0):

I've  identify the problem  and it was in  the  IIS  php version.It is set to  php 7.2 after I change it to php 5.5  it works