# How to get the size of the image?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array wanna get the size of the image:

```
$main_image = $product->images()->where('main_image', 1)->first();

if($main_image){
    $url = asset('uploads/products/'. $main_image['image']);

    $image[] = [
        "name"  => $main_image->image,
        "type"  => FileUploader::mime_content_type($main_image->image_path),

        "size"  => filesize($url),

        "file"  => $main_image->image_path,
        "local" => $main_image->image_path,
    ];
}
```

I got this error:

```
filesize(): stat failed for http://myapp.test/uploads/products/83QhiRFarGpV.jpeg
```

Even my image exists in the folder!:

[image]

I tried all the options in this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995731/laravel-get-size-from-uploaded-file) but still same error at all!

Comment: `filesize('uploads/products/'. $main_image['image']);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you so much, why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Are you saying that when you change the code to `"size"  => filesize('uploads/products/'. $main_image['image']),` it still does not work?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, worked perfectly! I mean why my shut does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using `asset()` to generate the `$url`:

`http://myapp.test/uploads/products/83QhiRFarGpV.jpeg`

The `filesize()` function works with local files, not URLs.

`filesize($main_image->image_path)` should work since you are using it in the line above to get the file type.

You probably also have another issue with

```
   "file"  => $main_image->image_path,
   "local" => $main_image->image_path,
```

Where you probably want the file to be `$url` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much worked like @RiggsFolly mention! filesize('uploads/products/'. $main_image['image']);